# Make navigation area opaque in Xcode 6

Tags: xcode, xcode6, osx-yosemite

Is there a way to make [navigation area](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-general/Chapters/AbouttheNavigatorArea.html) opaque in Xcode6?

I am constantly annoyed by various colors of underlaying windows visible in that area (blue in the picture below).

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't disable it on a per-app basis. You can disable it entirely:

```
$ defaults write com.apple.universalaccess reduceTransparency -bool true
```

Or you can check "Reduce Transparency" in Accessibility preferences:

[image]